# What fraction of the fund should one bet?

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling, operations-research, gambling

Say we have a gambler who makes money through sports betting. My aim is to develop a model to help our gambler maximise his winnings and minimize losses.

In my model, rather than betting a fixed amount of money, the gambler bets a certain **fraction** $0 < r < 1$ of his current betting fund. He continues betting that fraction as his betting fund increases or decreases until he cashes out after a certain number of sessions $n$.

The gambler's initial fund shall be $F_0$. His fund after $i$ sessions shall be $F_i$.

His **probability** of making a correct prediction shall be $0 < p < 1$. If our gambler had a $p$ of $0$ or $1$, then the entire model would be useless.

The average **odds** with which our gambler deals with is $a > 1$.

The gambler's minimum **desired profit** upon cash out is $T$.

$$T \le F_n - F_0 \tag{1}$$

If we expressed everything as a multiple of $F_0$, $(1)$ can be rewritten as:

$$T \le F_n - 1 \tag{1.1}$$

It follows that the following are known: $T$, $a$, $F_0$, $p$.

Should our gambler **lose** a particular session say $i+1$,

$$F_{i+1} = (1-r)F_i \tag{2.1}$$

Should he **win** that particular session

$$F_{i+1} = F_i(1-r + ra) \tag{2.2}$$

Given that the gambler plays $n$ sessioms before cashing out.

His expected number of wins = $p*n$        $(3.1)$

His expected number of losses = $(1-p)*n$         $(3.2)$

Now there are many different ways to distribute the gambler's losses and wins{$n \Bbb P pn$} and while calculating all scenarios and finding average $F_n$ may be ideal, it is computationally **very** expensive. So I decided to  model the problem assuming the losses take place in the worst way possible( back to back at the very beginning of the match).

The gambler's revenue after $n$ matches is given by the formula:

$F_n = (1-r)^{(1-p)n}\{(1-r)+ra\}^{pn}$             $(4)$

Now we know that our gambler wants to make a minimum profit of $T$ so we transform $(4)$ into an inequality using $(1.1)$

We get:

$(1-r)^{(1-p)n}\{(1-r)+ra\}^{pn}$ $ \ge T + 1$         $(4.1)$

Taking the Natural logarithm of both sides, I get:

$ln(1-r)*(1-p)(n) + ln(1-r + ra)*pn \ge ln(T+1)$           $(4.2)$

$n\{ln(1-r)(1-p) + ln(r(a-1)+1)(p) \} \ge ln(T+1)$    $(4.3)$

Giving the constraints on the variables and constants, I want to determine the minimum value of $n$ and maximum value of $r$ that satisfies $(4.1) / (4.3)$ (whichever is easier to solve) for any given $T$, $a$, $p$.

**MAJOR EDIT**

Thanks to @Rodrigo de Azevedo, I discovered Kelly's Criterion. I was sold on it, and decided to implement it into my gambling method.

For the purposes of my method Kelly's criterion is given by:

$r_i = p - $ ${1 - p}\over{a_i - 1}$  $(5)$

Where:

$r_i$ is the ratio at session $i$

$a_i$ is the odds at session $i$

Now $r: 0 \lt r \lt 1$  $(5.1)$

Applying $(5.1)$ to $(5)$ we get:

${p(a - 1) - (1 -p)}\over{a - 1}$ $ \gt \frac{0}{1}$

Cross multiply.

$p(a-1) - (1 - p) \gt 0(a-1)$

$pa - p - 1 + p \gt 0$

$pa - 1 > 0$

$pa > 1$

$p > 1/a$  $(5.2)$

Now that that's out of the way, we still have the problem of determining minimum $n$ such that we make a profit $ \ge T$.

In order to do this, we'll assume a "mean" value for $a$ then find the minimum value for $n$ that satisfies $(4.1)$

Due to the fact, that you do not know the odds for the matches in advance, your mean odds at $i$ say $a_{\mu i}$ may not be the mean odds at $n$ $a_{\mu n}$. In order to protect against this(and because I'm not a very big risk taker), I'll assume a value for $a_{\mu}$, that is less than $a_{\mu}$ called $a_{det}$.

$a_{det} = a_{\mu} - k\sigma$

Where $a_{\mu}$ is the **Geometric Mean** as opposed to the arithmetic mean of the odds and $\sigma$ is associated S.D

Using Chebyshev's Inequality, at least $k^{2} - 1 \over k^2$ of the distribution of the odds lie above $a_{det}$.

Picking a $k$ of $2.5$

$2.5^{2}-1\over 2.5^{2}$

$0.84$

So our $a_{det}$ is lower than at least $84$% of the distribution of the odds. This is safe enough for me.

$a_{det} = a_{\mu} - 2.5\sigma$

Using $a_{det}$, we'll calculate the minimum $n$ that satisfies $(4.1)$

Subbing $5$ and $a_{det}$ into $(4.1)$ we get:

$\left(1-\left(p - \frac{1-p}{a_{det}-1}  \right) \right)^{n - np} \cdot \left(\left(p - \frac{1-p}{a_{det}-1}  \right)\cdot(a_{det} - 1)\right)^{np}$  $ \ge T + 1$   $(6.0)$

This can be simplified further to:
$\left({a_{det}-1-(pa_{det}-1)}\over{a_{det}-1}\right)^{n(1-p)}\cdot\left(pa_{det}-1+1\right)^{np}$

$\left({a_{det}-pa_{det}}\over{a_{det}-1}\right)^{n(1-p)}\cdot\left(pa_{det}\right)^{np}$

$\left(\left(\frac{a_{det}*(1-p)}{a_{det}-1}\right)^{n(1-p)}\cdot\left(pa_{det}\right)^{np}\right)$ $(6.1)$

P.S due to my particularly low $a_{det}$ we'll likely make much more profit than $T$, but that's loads better than choosing a higher $a_{det}$ and making less.

Comment: Average odds? Shouldn't the odds be fixed?

Comment: Do you try sports betting? If you do, you'd know thst the odds vary from match to match. It's possible to find matches with exactly the same odds, but unless you're dealing with **completely** fixed leagues you won't be gambling on such matches. I've never done sports betting before, but I did do research before trying to model it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to focus on bets with fixed odds, like roulette?

Comment: The odds change, but when you place a bet, you know what the odds are. Hence, shouldn't the time-varying odds $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}$ be inputs?

Comment: You're right, but this model needs to determine your ratio and number of sessions **before** you start betting. At session $i$, you don't know yet what odds session $i+k$ will have. So we find the average odds of the matches you bet on. S.D should be very small. Bet on matches with similar odds.

Comment: I developed this model to make money through sports betting. Don't have access to Roulette.

Comment: I think this should be a control theory problem. Namely, the ratio put at stake in each session should be a function of the odds at that session, i.e., $$r_i = \kappa (a_i)$$ where $\kappa$ is a function to be determined.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I did not know control theory existed before now. 1. How do I add it as a tag. 2 any idea how to determine $\kappa$? It will in turn probably be a function of $T$, $P$ and maybe $n$?(which needs to be determined.

Comment: Any Idea how to make the problem more tractable. I have some suggestions. Since I don't know control theory, I was hoping you could implement them. First we play it **safe** In determining $r$, for each session, that given a particular upper bound for $n$, which we'll call $n_max$, there exist a range of possible values of $r$ and $n$, which will provide a solution for the given $a$, $p$ and $T$. The $r$ at each odd will be determined as the **maximum** $r$, such that desired profit can be realised in minimum $n$.    A little tweaking may be required.

Comment: In determining our range of values for $r$, and $n$ after deciding upon $n_max$ I want us to still play it safe. We'll first get a table of aĺl past odds, then find tge average $a_mean$, and the $SD$. We'll pick a value **exactly 2 $SD$ below the mean $a_det$. We'll use $a_det$ in determining our range of values. ($a_det$ may be made lower than 2 $SD$ if our odds distribution is non-normal. Aim is to choose an $a_det$ such that it is \lt 95% of odds.- We're playing safe here). Using $a_det$ we'll construct $\kappa$ taking our minimum $n$ that satisfied the inequality.

Comment: $\kappa$ will be the function which produced the **maximum** $r$ for that $a_det$ that satisfied the inequality for **minimum** $n$. We can then use $\kappa$ to generate the $r$ for each $a_i$ I expect larger $a_i$ will have larger $r$. Any ideas how to develop $\kappa$?

Comment: Are you acquainted with the [Kelly criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion)?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [these](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kelly-criterion).

Comment: Nope. I am most definitely not. My maths may be Highschool level(Bar calculus which I skipped classes on). I know some University Maths, but I'm in a shit university so... I'll look up your links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the minimum $n$ that satisfies $(6.1)$.

$\left(\left(\frac{a_{det}∗(1−p)}{a_{det}−1}\right)^{n(1−p)}\cdot\left(pa_{det}\right)^{np}\right) \ge T+1$  $(6.1)$

On the LHS, $n$ is a common exponent. Take the natural logarithm of both sides

$ln\left(\frac{a_{det}∗(1−p)}{a_{det}−1}\right)\cdot{n(1−p)} +  ln\left(pa_{det}\right)\cdot{np} \ge ln(T+1)$

Factorise LHS with $n$.

$n\left(ln\left(\frac{a_{det}∗(1−p)}{a_{det}−1}\right)\cdot(1−p) +  ln\left(pa_{det}\right)\cdot p\right) \ge ln(T+1)$  $(6.2)$

Rewriting $(6.2)$

$n \ge \left({ln(T+1)}\over{ln\left(\frac{a_{det}∗(1−p)}{a_{det}−1}\right)\cdot(1−p) +  ln\left(pa_{det}\right)\cdot p}\right)$   $(6.3)$

Presto.

I realised this worked because Kelly's criterion aimed to maximise expected logarithmic growth.

Answer (score 4):

Given

- odds $\omega_1, \omega_2, \dots, \omega_n  > 1$.
- probabilities of winning $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n \in [0,1]$.

let

- $X_0, X_1, \dots, X_n$ be *random variables* that denote the fund's size at step $k$.
- $u_k \in [0,1]$ be the fraction of the fund to be put at stake at step $k$. Let $u_k$ depend solely on $\omega_k$ and $p_k$, and **not** on $X_{k-1}$. Hence, $u_k$ is **not** a random variable.

Hence, we have the discrete-time stochastic process

$$X_k = \begin{cases} (1 + (\omega_k - 1) \, u_k) \, X_{k-1} & \text{with probability } p_k\\\\ (1 - u_k) \, X_{k-1} & \text{with probability } 1-p_k\end{cases}$$

---

#### Maximizing the expected return

The return at step $k$ is, thus,

$$R_k := \frac{X_k - X_{k-1}}{X_{k-1}} = \frac{X_k}{X_{k-1}} - 1 = \begin{cases} (\omega_k - 1) \, u_k & \text{with probability } p_k\\\\ - u_k & \text{with probability } 1 - p_k\end{cases}$$

Taking the expected value of the return, we obtain

$$\mathbb E (R_k) = (\omega_k - 1) \, u_k \, p_k - u_k \, (1 - p_k) = (\omega_k \, p_k - 1) \, u_k$$

Maximizing the expected value of the return,

$$\bar{u}_k := \arg \max_{u_k \in [0,1]} \mathbb E \left( R_k \right) = \arg \max_{u_k \in [0,1]} (\omega_k \, p_k - 1) \, u_k = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } \omega_k \, p_k - 1 > 0\\ 0 & \text{if } \omega_k \, p_k - 1 \leq 0\end{cases}$$

where $\omega_k \, p_k - 1$ is the expected profit per unit bet at step $k$. Thus, the *optimal betting policy*, $\bar{u}_k = \pi (\omega_k, p_k)$, is

$$\boxed{\pi (\omega, p) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } \omega \, p > 1\\ 0 & \text{if } \omega \, p \leq 1\end{cases}}$$

In words,

- when the expected profit is *non-positive*, we bet *nothing*.
- when the expected profit is *positive*, we go *all in*.

Needless to say, this is an extremely aggressive betting policy. It would be wise to maximize another objective function.

---

#### Maximizing the expected logarithmic growth

Taking the expected value of the logarithm of the growth at step $k$,

$$\mathbb E \left[ \log \left( \frac{X_k}{X_{k-1}} \right) \right] = \mathbb E \left[\log (1 + R_k)\right] = p_k \log \left( 1 + (\omega_k - 1) \, u_k \right) + (1 - p_k) \log \left( 1 - u_k \right)$$

Using [SymPy](http://live.sympy.org) to find where the derivative with respect to $u_k$ vanishes,

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> p, u, w = symbols('p u w')
>>> f = p * log(1 + (w-1) * u) + (1 - p) * log(1 - u) 
>>> diff(f,u)
  p*(w - 1)     -p + 1
------------- - ------
u*(w - 1) + 1   -u + 1
>>> solve(diff(f,u),u)
 p*w - 1 
[-------]
  w - 1
```

Hence,

$$\bar{u}_k := \arg \max_{u_k \in [0,1]} \mathbb E \left[ \log \left( \frac{X_k}{X_{k-1}} \right) \right] = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\omega_k \, p_k - 1}{\omega_k - 1} & \text{if } \omega_k \, p_k - 1 > 0\\\\ 0 & \text{if } \omega_k \, p_k - 1 \leq 0\end{cases}$$

where $\omega_k \, p_k - 1$ is the expected profit per unit bet at step $k$. This is the [Kelly betting policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) [0]

$$\boxed{\pi (\omega, p) := \begin{cases} \dfrac{\omega \, p - 1}{\omega - 1} & \text{if } \omega \, p > 1\\\\ 0 & \text{if } \omega \, p \leq 1\end{cases}}$$

We again bet nothing when the expected profit is non-positive, but we no longer go all in when the expected profit is positive. Note that

$$\dfrac{\omega \, p - 1}{\omega - 1} = 1 - \left(\frac{\omega}{\omega - 1}\right) (1 - p) \leq 1$$

---

#### Reference

[0] Edward O. Thorp, [The Kelly criterion in blackjack, sports betting, and the stock market](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-044453248-0.50015-0), The 10th International Conference on Gambling and Risk Taking, Montreal, June 1997.

Comment: I am assuming the gambler has a fixed probability of getting any game right $p$. **NOT** varying probabilities on each game. The gambler **only** places bets on matches they're sure om

Comment: Some of your calcs are Greek to me. Regardless, your conclusion seems weird to me. The aim is **NOT** to maximise return at $X_k$, but maximise return **only** at $X_n$. We're looking at maximising returns after $n$ rounds. A formula to calculate $r$ at each round $k$ with odds $\mu_k$ and probability $p$. I offered something I thought might work in a comment to the question.

Comment: I looked at the Kelly criterion. I love it. Just one problem that I have: The Kelly criterion tells me nothing of my $n$. I know from brute force simulation with Excel, that the optimum $r$ for different $n$ changes even while $n$ is constant. Is there any way for us yo extend the Kelly criterion.

Comment: I wasn't criticising you. My math is grossly insufficient, and I've been working on improving it. I'm currently trying to test the Kelky criterion recommended $r$ over my brute-forced solutions for $r$ for any given $n$.

Comment: Using Kelly's criterion doesn't produce the optimum ratio for a given $n$. I guess it produces optimum $r$ for sufficiently large $n$, but not for smaller $n$. Any way to work around this.

Comment: The Kelly criterion maximizes your expected return over "the long term."  And the conclusion to wager $\frac {edge}{odds}$ works even if your edge and odds are changing.  There is a softer interpretation that says to never wager more than than the Kelly formula, but it is okay to wager less.  That is wagering more increases risk ($\sigma$) without increasing return ($\mu$) which would be irrational.  While wagering less reduces both risk and return, which may be rational depending on your risk tolerance.

Comment: I've updated my question following my discovery and incorporation of Kelly's criterion into my betting strategy

Comment: Really good answer. I came here from another question (that I [have also answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4324571/909869)), and you linked to this one, and I believe mine (worst in every sense), could be complement to yours, since I believe this one, being very tecnical as is also E. Thorp paper and the wiki for the Kelly Criterion (or even worst Kelly's paper), for the beginner reader it kind of miss part of the intuition related to why make sense to use it: mine at the beginning present in my opinion in a more intuitive way why the expexted value of the logarithm pops up.