# Proof that the Kelly Criterion is optimal?

Tags: optimization, information-theory, gambling

Let's say you are betting on the outcome of some random variable. You can invest any amount $X$, and each outcome multiples that amount $X$ by a certain amount $ \ge 0$. You must choose $X$ less than how much capital you have. A [Kelly Bet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) is one in which you bet an amount that maximizes the logarithm of your capital. The Kelly Bet will allow your capital to grow larger than any other betting scheme in the long term (i.e., as the number of bets approaches infinity).

What is the proof that previous statement?

Comment: Optimal with respect to what? As bets a probabilistic, this question should be made more precise in my opinion.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2034537/339790)

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false.

For example consider the bet where you double your money with probability $2/3$ and lose it otherwise. Now consider the strategy "bet \$1 more than the Kelly bet on the first turn, and then use the Kelly bet after that". If this wins on the first turn it will forever have more money than the Kelly strategy, and if it loses on the first turn it will forever have less money than the Kelly strategy. So no matter how large the number of bets becomes, it has a $2/3$ chance of having a larger amount than the Kelly strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is in your link, [Kelly's original paper](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ewbialek/rome/refs/kelly_56.pdf) and many subsequent papers but the key part here is the number of bets must very large. If you were bet-limited to, say, 4 bets to earn 16x your money, you're forced to bet your whole bankroll on double or nothing for any chance of success. That doesn't violate Kelly.

In fact, Thorpe of Fortune's Formula fame briefly explains on [pages 11 and 12](https://www.eecs.harvard.edu/cs286r/courses/fall12/papers/Thorpe_KellyCriterion2007.pdf) that the optimal betting pattern for limited bets is not necessarily Kelly. Per your phrasing, Kelly is correct. Further, the capital growing larger than any essentially different betting pattern means Kelly will achieve a targeted capital size in the fewest bets.

**This "essentially different" betting pattern refutes Oscar Cunningham's answer:**
a) If one dollar is insignificant to your total bankroll / capital then it's same essential strategy.
b) If one dollar is, in fact, significant then that $1 extra is overbetting. Betting > 1.0 Kelly on even 1 bet reduces the growth rate of your capital while increasing [risk of ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_of_ruin). It is suboptimal in the long run.

Betting fractional Kelly is actually far more common than full Kelly, in order to reduce the risk of ruin. The growth rate is reduced less significantly in comparison.

Comment: "Betting > 1.0 Kelly on even 1 bet reduces the growth rate of your capital while increasing risk of ruin."  @OscarCunningham refutes this with a counterexample.  Repeating a false assertion can't make it true.

Comment: No, @OscarCunningham is wrong because he misconstrues "essentially different" and ignores risk of ruin. If 1.0 Kelly calls for a 100 bet and I bet 101, I'd argue the 1.01 Kelly bet is essentially the same but say the bets are small to make one dollar matter. Oscar has 2/3 the chance to be ahead after 1 bet, yes. Short term, Kelly is worse. Long term, the lower bankroll from the 1/3 chance of losing gives a higher chance of bankruptcy. On average, after many trials and accounting for risk of ruin, the one dollar overbet is worse.

Comment: There is no chance of bankruptcy in the @OscarCunningham strategy.

Answer (score -1):

Say in total I have 1 dollar to start with and I bet $X$ amount of my current net worth each time. Say if I win a bet (with probability $p$), I will get $X b$ back (net odd of $b$). Then after the bet with probability $p$, I got back

$1+Xb$

and with probability $1-b$, I will have

$1-X$

left.

Now, consider betting for $N$ times, then there will be about $Np$ win and $N(1-p)$ loss. So, the final amount is about

$(1+Xb)^{Np} (1-X)^{N(1-p)}=((1+Xb)^{p} (1-X)^{1-p})^N.$

To maximize this gain, we just need to maximize $(1+Xb)^{p} (1-X)^{1-p}$ with respect to $X$. Or we can maximize $f(X)=\ln [(1+Xb)^{p} (1-X)^{1-p}]$ instead. Setting $\frac{d f}{d X}=0$, we have $\frac{pb}{1+Xb}-\frac{1-p}{1-X}=0\Rightarrow X= \frac{bp-(1-p)}{b}.$

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but what you seem to imply ("the final amount is about") is that that the expected wealth will be $E[W]=(1+Xb)^{Np} (1-X)^{N(1-p)}=((1+Xb)^{p} (1-X)^{1-p})^N$. Can you prove this? As far as I can tell this is not correct. You're also implying that the Kelly criterion maximizes $\ln(E[W])$ when in fact it it maximizes $E[\ln(W)]$.

Comment: The expected wealth is $(1+Xb)^{Np} (1-X)^{N(1-p)}$ but we should not maximize this or even $E[W/N]$ directly as both are unbounded as $N$ goes to infinity. On the other hand, by the law of large number, $\frac{1}{N}\ln W$ will converge to $E[\frac{1}{N}\ln W]$ and we would like to maximize the latter instead. The above is equivalent of that.