# How to derive the Kelly criterion when bet size options are not continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, gambling

If there was a game with only a limited number of betting options each providing even odds. Given a player's probability of winning $p$ how can you determine the bet sizes to choose for each value of the portfolio to optimise the growth rate as per the normal Kelly criterion?

edit:
bet size options are with a starting portfolio value of 1500

[50,100,500,2500,10000,50000,100000,250000,500000,1000000,2500000,4000000,5000000,10000000,15000000,25000000]

however I am also interested in the answer for the general case

my intuition says that the answer would be to just choose the bet size that maximises the expected log portfolio value for that turn however I am struggling to prove this.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2034537/339790). Maximize over your finite set, rather than over $[0,1]$.

Comment: This is what I am thinking is correct but how do I prove that maximising the log(X) at each step will maximise it over multiple steps in the finite case

Comment: If you want to maximize a function over a finite set, just evaluate at each element and then take the maximum. More programming than mathematics.

Comment: but the kelly criterion is trying to maximise log(X) at the end of n steps not at each step.

Comment: According to whom?

Comment: erm according to kelly... The definition boils down to maximising E [log(Xn)]  or E[ log (Xn/Xo) ^(1/n)]

Comment: I probably considered a $1$-step approach due to time-varying odds and probabilities. It was based on Thorp's [paper](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/cs286r/courses/fall12/papers/Thorpe_KellyCriterion2007.pdf). I stand by my suggestion. You have a single optimization problem. You have a finite set of options. Just evaluate the objective function at each option and then find the maximum.

Comment: Sorry but I am looking for a proof that this maximises the value of log(Xn) simply giving a suggestion which I indicated I was already considering in the question is not helpful. While it is easy to show in the case where the fraction bet can be constant that maximising at each step is the same thing as maximising log(Xn) that is not the case in this example.

Comment: Let me know when you find it.