# Geometric growth rate and Kelly's Criterion question

Tags: probability, finance, mathematical-modeling, economics, gambling

In the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion#:%7E:text=11%20External%20links-,optimal%20betting%20example) page about Kelly Criterion, the author calculated the expected wealth after N bets as $$W * (1+g)^N$$ where $W$ is the initial wealth, and $g$ is the expected geometric growth rate. For example, with \$25 starting wealth, a 60% chance of winning/losing the whatever you wager, if our strategy is to bet 20% of current wealth, then the article says that  $1+g = (1+0.2*1)^{0.6}(1-0.2*1)^{0.4} = 1.02034$ and expected wealth at round N is $W_N = 25*(1.02034)^N$

But if I look at it from another perspective: the expected wealth after 1 round is $0.6(1.2W) + 0.4(0.8W) = 1.04W$. So shouldn't $W_N$ be $25*(1.04)^N$ instead?

That is, there should only be one answer for expected wealth at round N, given our paramters p,q,f (here f is known so Kelly Criterion doesn't really come into play). However, the Wiki page has a completely different computation than what I have.

Comment: If we start with $E(W_N) = W(1+g)^N$ as written in the article, then it is true that $1+g = \left[E\left( \frac{W_N}{W}\right)\right]^{1/N}$  but this is not equal to $1$ plus the expected geometric growth rate $E\left[\left(\frac{W_N}{W}\right)^{1/N} \right]$ -- which is maximized in the Kelly criterion.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2034537/339790)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of the Kelly Criterion is to maximize the expected geometric growth rate -- not the expected arithmetic return and not the expected terminal wealth. Your reasoning about computing expected values is not incorrect, but it is not what is used in deriving the Kelly Criterion.

With fractional betting, the wealth $W_n$ after $n$ rounds is

$$W_n = W_{n-1}(1+fX_n),$$

where $f$ is the fixed deterministic fraction and $X_n$ is a binary random variable such that $p =\mathbb{P}(X_n = +1)$ and $q= 1-p = \mathbb{P}(X_n = -1)$.

The expected wealth after $n$ rounds conditional on the wealth after $n-1$ rounds, $W_{n-1}$, is

$$\mathbb{E}(W_n\,| W_{n-1}) = W_{n-1}\left[p(1+f)-q(1-f) \right],$$

and for $f = 20\%$, $p = 60\%$ and $q = 40\%$ we obtain

$$\mathbb{E}(W_n\,| W_{n-1}) = W_{n-1}[0.6(1+0.2) +0.4(1-0.2)]= 1.04W_{n-1}$$

This is similar to what you derivived as far as it goes.

**Derivation of the Kelly Criterion**

The Kelly Criterion is derived by maximizing the expected geometric growth rate

$$\tag{*}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}\log \frac{W_n}{W_0}\right],$$

which is not the same as

$$\frac{1}{n} \log  \frac{\mathbb{E}(W_n)}{W_0}$$

The terminal wealth after $n$ rounds is

$$W_n = W_0\prod_{k=1}^n (1+fX_k)$$

Taking the logarithm of both sides we get

$$\log W_n = \log W_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n \log(1+fX_k)$$

Whence, for independent and identically distributed $X_k$,

$$\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{1}{n}\log  \frac{W_n}{W_0}\right] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\log(1+fX_1)]= \mathbb{E}[\log(1+fX_1)]\\ = p\log (1+f) +q\log(1-f)$$

To find the maximum, take the derivative with respect to $f$ and equate to $0$.  The Kelly optimal fraction will be $f^* = p-q$.

**Resolution**

With a fractional betting strategy we always have

$$\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{W_n}{W_0}\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{k=1}^n (1+f X_k)\right]= \prod_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}(1+fX_1) = (1 + (p-q)f)^n$$

and, hence,

$$\tag{1}\left[\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{W_n}{W_0}\right)\right]^{1/n} = 1 + (p-q)f$$

To maximize (1) we would choose $f=1$ (betting all accumulated wealth on each round) and we would get $\mathbb{E}(W_n) = W_0(1+p-q))^n$. However, there would be a minuscule probability of attaining this wealth as the probability of ruin is $P_{\text{ruin}} = 1 - p^n$ which approaches $1$ rapidly as $n$ is increased.

However, (1) is not the expected growth rate that is maximized by Kelly Criterion. That would be

$$g(f) = \mathbb{E}\left[\log \left(\frac{W_n}{W_0}\right)^{1/n}\right], $$

which is maximized with $\text{argmax }\, g(f)=f^*=p-q$ and

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\log \left(\frac{W_n}{W_0}\right)^{1/n}\right] = g(f^*) = p\log(1+f^*) + q\log(1- f^*)$$

It is true that with the optimal betting fraction,

$$\exp\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\log \left(\frac{W_n}{W_0}\right)^{1/n}\right] \right)= (1+f^*)^p(1-f^*)^q,$$

but this does not mean $\mathbb{E}(W_n) = W_0[1+g(f^*)]^n$.

Comment: Thanks. My question is probably unclear but it really has little to do with Kelly Criterion. The only reason I mentioned it is because my confusion came from an example cited in KC's Wiki page.

Basically,  there's only 1 way to calculate expected wealth at round N. KC's Wiki page seemed to suggest it's W(1+g)^n, while you and I both think it should also be W[1+(p-q)f]^n. But they obviously are not the same!

Comment: @wwyws:  It was unclear but now I can see what you are asking.  Let me revise the answer.

Comment: @wwyws:  There is still a problem with this.  The wording in Wiki is part of the problem. Another is if it is true that $\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{k=1}^n (1+fX_k) \right] = \prod_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}(1+fX_k)$

Comment: Yea it's likely the wording in Wiki's article is inaccurate. Your second point should be true since $X_k$ are iid.